# Exporting Ms Access Table to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I use this code but it says " Compile Error: Expected End Sub" 
Sorry im not good with this. But willing to learn.

```
Private Sub Command125_Click()
Public Function TransferToExcel()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler


Dim strTable As String
Dim strWorkSheetPath As String

strWorkSheetPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\"
strWorkSheetPath = strWorkSheetPath & "APK.xlsx"
strTable = "tblRegistration"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acExport, _
spredsheettype:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
TableNmae:=strTable, FileName:=strWorkSheetPath, _
hasfieldnames:=True

ErrorHandlerExit:
Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number _
& "; Description: " & Err.Description
Resume ErrorHandlerExit

End Function
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove ```Private Sub Command125_Click()``` from the very beginning and remove ```End Sub``` from the very end.